# Standardize the Samples (Compute the z-Score)

Tags: code-golf, math, array, arithmetic, statistics

Given a list of floating point numbers, [*standardize it*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

#### Details

- A list \$x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\$ is *standardized* if the *mean* of all values is 0, and the *standard deviation* is 1. One way to compute this is by first computing the mean \$\mu\$ and the standard deviation \$\sigma\$ as
  $$ \mu = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \qquad \sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\mu)^2} ,$$
  and then computing the standardization by replacing every \$x_i\$ with \$\frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}\$.
- You can assume that the input contains at least two distinct entries (which implies \$\sigma \neq 0\$).
- Note that some implementations use the sample standard deviation, which is not equal to the population standard deviation \$\sigma\$ we are using here.
- There is a [CW answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177602/24877) for all [trivial solutions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/should-we-combine-answers-where-the-same-code-works-in-many-different-languages/11218#11218).

#### Examples

```
[1,2,3] -> [-1.224744871391589,0.0,1.224744871391589]
[1,2] -> [-1,1]
[-3,1,4,1,5] -> [-1.6428571428571428,-0.21428571428571433,0.8571428571428572,-0.21428571428571433,1.2142857142857144]
```

(These examples have been generated with [this script](https://tio.run/##VY7NDoIwEITvPMUcOEACEvFmlJMXnwExqaECsV20P5H48rVFY/CyO5n9dmd7pm9cCOe0YdQy1Q4vju0W9WG0F8Eb5NVPR0tGYI/kNIV5MuXSpoUeOslS7OIKIgKePVccXgAUiuevapRHMrxTTCCG4NSZfoYBaT@MttLfLkCzO98M7kMZrJAUlPoWmPg//Vx@k51kA/mNuxrIeGr5c73OymzTuDc).)

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>51</s> <s>45</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

Thanks to Giuseppe and J.Doe!

```r
function(x)scale(x)/(1-1/sum(x|1))^.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrM4OTEnFUjraxjqGuoXl@ZqVNQYamrG6Zn@T9NI1jDUMdIx1tTkgrKhLF1jHUMdEyA21dT8/x8A)

Comment: Beat me by 2 bytes and 1 minute

Answer (score 5):

## CW for all [trivial entries](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/should-we-combine-answers-where-the-same-code-works-in-many-different-languages/11218#11218)

---

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + scipy, 31 bytes

```python
from scipy.stats import*
zscore
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehODmzoFKvuCSxpFghM7cgv6hEi6uqODm/KPX/fwA)

## Octave / MATLAB, 15 bytes

```matlab
@(x)zscore(x,1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCs6o4Ob8oVaNCx1Dzf1p@UW5iiUJOfl46V2JesUa0rrGOoY4JEJvGav4HAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```apl
(-÷.5*⍨⊢÷⌹×≢)+/-⊢×≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBA3dw9v1TLUe9a541LXo8PZHPTsPT3/UuUhTW18XJABiAxUqHFpvrGCoYALEpgA)

`⊢÷⌹` is sum of squares

`⊢÷⌹×≢` is sum of squares divided by length

Comment: Wow. I shouldn't be surprised anymore, but I am every time

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, <s>41,32</s> 30 bytes

9 bytes saved thanks to Erik + 2 more thanks to ngn

```
x←v-(+/v)÷⍴v←⎕⋄x÷(+/x×x÷⍴v)*.5
```

Prompts for vector of numbers and calculates mean standard deviation and standardised elements of input vector

Comment: Can't you assign `x←v-(+/v)÷⍴v←⎕` and then do `x÷((+/x*2)÷⍴v)*.5`?

Comment: I can indeed. Thanks.

Comment: does apl+win do singleton extension (`1 2 3+,4` ←→ `1 2 3+4`)? if yes, you could rewrite `(+/x*2)÷⍴v` as `+/x×x÷⍴v`

Comment: @ngn That works for another 2 bytes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
tYm-t&1Zs/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQyV7dEzTCqWP///2hdYx1DHRMgNo0FAA)

#### Explanation

```
t       % Implicit input
        % Duplicate
Ym      % Mean
-       % Subtract, element-wise
t       % Duplicate
&1Zs    % Standard deviation using normalization by n
/       % Divide, element-wise
        % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + pryr, <s>53</s> 52 bytes

-1 byte using `sum(x|1)` instead of `length(x)` as seen in @Robert S.'s solution

```r
pryr::f((x-(y<-mean(x)))/(sum((x-y)^2)/sum(x|1))^.5)
```

For being a language built for statisticians, I'm amazed that this doesn't have a built-in function. At least not one that I could find. Even the function `mosaic::zscore` doesn't yield the expected results. This is likely due to using the population standard deviation instead of sample standard deviation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlBCoAgFAX3neQ/0CLNTdRVhAitRUpYQZ7@l@BiYJhJ7Gc@U07j6IleSXmSwS2RXgAdXU8oNcMqdIeL272XY1sD9rRSL5TQQFO9mtSiF8OPAZg/)

Comment: You can change the `<-` into a `=` to save 1 byte.

Comment: @J.Doe nope, I used the method I commented on Robert S.'s solution. `scale` is neat!

Comment: @J.Doe since you only use `n` once you can use it directly for [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQrM4OTEnFUhraRjqGuoXl@ZqVNQYamrG6eqZ/k/TSNYw1DHSMdbU5IKyoSxdYx1DHRMgNtXU/P8fAA)

Comment: @Giuseppe Wouldn't you be able to use pryr::f, it would implicitly guess your x, saving 2 bytes? Also, if I include the R + pryr, do we really need to use pryr::?

Comment: @Sumner18 the `pryr::` is part of the code, the "+ pryr" is just to indicate that you are using an R package instead of base R for your answer. It's more of a Code Golf rules thing.

Comment: @J.Doe Is the extra output created from the `scale` function allowed? Or would that be up to the creator of the challenge?

Comment: @RobertS. here on PPCG we tend to encourage allowing flexible input and output, including outputting more than is required, with the exception of challenges where the precise layout of the output is the whole point of the challenge.

Comment: Of course R built-ins wouldn't use "population variance". Only confused engineers would use such a thing (hencethe Python and Matlab answers ;))

Answer (score 3):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 126 bytes

```
proc S L {lmap c $L {expr ($c-[set m ([join $L +])/[set n [llength $L]].])/sqrt(([join [lmap c $L {expr ($c-$m)**2}] +])/$n)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYy9CsMgHMT3PsUNDpqSliTtW3TLKP@hiPQDNUYtFILPbm3okKHDwd3vjkvKlOLDpDDigsXYq4cCq1a/fQBnqpVRJ1hw@Zwe7lvtSRxX6CCN0e6W7hUTHSqPc0j8N5X/3pgVTdNnWl@YEzkX/0oRcsTSoceQabcF29gO6HCqOmcqHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```apl
{d÷.5*⍨l÷⍨+/×⍨d←⍵-(+/⍵)÷l←≢⍵}
```

*-4 bytes thanks to @ngn*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///vzrl8HY9U61HvStyDm8Hktr6h6cDqZRHbRMe9W7V1dDWB1Kah7fngAQ6FwE5tf/TwJJ9j/qmevo/6mo@tN74UdtEIC84yBlIhnh4Bv9PUzBUMFIw5gLTQBKoBsgyAWJTAA)

Comment: you could assign `⍵-m` to a variable and remove `m←` like this: `{d÷.5*⍨l÷⍨+/×⍨d←⍵-(+/⍵)÷l←≢⍵}`

Comment: @ngn Ah, nice, thanks, I didn't see that duplication somehow

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
_ÆmµL½÷ÆḊ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@cFvuoa0@h/Ye3n647eGOrsPT////H61rrGOoYwLEprEA)

It's not any shorter, but Jelly's determinant function `ÆḊ` also calculates vector norm.

```
_Æm             x - mean(x)
   µ            then:
    L½          Square root of the Length
      ÷ÆḊ       divided by the norm
         ×      Multiply by that value
```

Comment: Hey, nice alternative! Unfortunately, I can't see a way to shorten it.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
Mean[(a=#-Mean@#)a]^-.5a&
```

Pure function. Takes a list of numbers as input and returns a list of machine-precision numbers as output. Note that the built-in `Standardize` function uses the sample variance by default.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Cows quack!

```
(-%[:%:1#.-*-%#@[)+/%#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9DVzXaStXKUFlPV0tXVdkhWlNbX1X5vyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagqGCkYIxEgfGjDcG8kyA2PQ/AA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>31</strike> 23 bytes

```
(-%[:%:#@[%~1#.-*-)+/%#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F9DVzXaStVK2SFatc5QWU9XS1dTW19V@b8ml5KegnqarZ66go5CrZVCWjEXV2pyRr5CmoKhgpGCMRIHxow3BvJMgNj0PwA)

```
                   +/%# - mean (sum (+/) divided (%) by the number of samples (#)) 
(                 )     - the list is a left argument here (we have a hook)
                 -      - the difference between each sample and the mean
                *       - multiplied by 
               -        - the difference between each sample and the mean
            1#.         - sum by base-1 conversion
          %~            - divided by
       #@[              - the length of the samples list
     %:                 - square root
   [:                   - convert to a fork (function composition) 
 -                      - subtract the mean from each sample
  %                     - and divide it by sigma
```

Comment: Rearranging it gives 22 `[:(%[:%:1#.*:%#)]-+/%#` https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8D/aSkM12krVylBZT8tKVVkzVldbX1X5vyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagqGCkYIxEgfGjDcG8kyA2PQ/AA, I think one of those caps could be removed, but haven't had any luck so far, EDIT: a more direct byteshaving is `(-%[:%:1#.-*-%#@[)+/%#` also at 22

Comment: @Cows quack Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>80</s> <s>75</s> 68 bytes

```
t x=k(/sqrt(f$sum$k(^2)))where k g=g.(-f(sum x)+)<$>x;f=(/sum(1<$x))
```

Thanks to @flawr for the suggestions to use `sum(1<$x)` instead of `sum[1|_<-x]` and to inline the mean, @xnor for inlining the standard deviation and other reductions.

Expanded:

```
-- Standardize a list of values of any floating-point type.
standardize :: Floating a => [a] -> [a]
standardize input = eachLessMean (/ sqrt (overLength (sum (eachLessMean (^2)))))
  where

    -- Map a function over each element of the input, less the mean.
    eachLessMean f = map (f . subtract (overLength (sum input))) input

    -- Divide a value by the length of the input.
    overLength n = n / sum (map (const 1) input)
```

Comment: You can replace `[1|_<-x]` with `(1<$x)` to save a few bytes. That is a great trick for avoiding the `fromIntegral`, that I haven't seen so far!

Comment: By the way: I like using [tryitonline](https://tio.run/##HcdNDoIwEAbQq3yLWXQiSsBlGS9iMGEBSPoTZcakty/E3XvvScMcY62GInE2BKyy3tzFXRPzQI/iF2TJrf6S6wYq7JMsdA7Fq@h3N/qXgnv1vGUE1yrXNJ0UfPYtGwiGZ9f0zX2sBw), you can run your code there and then copy the preformatted aswer for posting here!

Comment: And you [do not have to define](https://tio.run/##DchBDoIwEAXQq/xFFzMRS8AljBcxmrCgSFoaZcakt6/dvbz3onFNqVZDkbQaIjbZPF3oGkh/Bwozz@5epoAsuW9Fw@wKTyr6Pc0H38pFeo28Z0TqleuxNAo@554NDobH0I3d7Vn/) `m`.

Comment: You can write `(-x+)` for `(+(-x))` to avoid parens. Also it looks like `f` can be pointfree: `f=(/sum(1<$x))`, and `s` can be replaced with its definition.

Comment: @xnor Ooh, `(-x+)` is handy, I’m sure I’ll be using that in the future

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 7 bytes

```
▓-_²▓√/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtMm68Yc2AalHHbP0//@PNtQx0jGO5QLRQFLXWMdQxwSITWMB)

### Explanation

This is literally a byte-for-byte recreation of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer, but I save some bytes from MathGolf having 1-byters for everything needed for this challenge. Also the answer looks quite good in my opinion!

```
▓         get average of list
 -        pop a, b : push(a-b)
  _       duplicate TOS
   ²      pop a : push(a*a)
    ▓     get average of list
     √    pop a : push(sqrt(a)), split string to list
      /   pop a, b : push(a/b), split strings
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
_Æm÷²Æm½Ɗ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@cFvu4e2HNgGpQ3uPdan8//8/2lDHSMc4FgA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>80</s>  79 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>(x-g(a))/g(a.map(x=>(x-m)**2))**.5,g=a=>m=eval(a.join`+`)/a.length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYtLDoMwDET3PYlNkyCgLM1FqkpYNKSgfFBBiNunXiLRxbzFm5mZd16H77RsOqa3zSNlpo5N4AUO6uDQDhixFJ5cwKKoUWBa5UgOgezOXjZzmmJ/77Fk42102wfzkOKavDU@ORjhWalaNS/E29X/sbpRlXpIWinzDw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                      // given the input array a[]
  a.map(x =>              // for each value x in a[]:
    (x - g(a)) /          //   compute (x - mean(a)) divided by
    g(                    //   the standard deviation:
      a.map(x =>          //     for each value x in a[]:
        (x - m) ** 2      //       compute (x - mean(a))²
      )                   //     compute the mean of this array
    ) ** .5,              //   and take the square root
    g = a =>              //   g = helper function taking an array a[],
      m = eval(a.join`+`) //     computing the mean
          / a.length      //     and storing the result in m
  )                       // end of outer map()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>25</s> 19 bytes

```
≧⁻∕ΣθＬθθＩ∕θ₂∕ΣＸθ²Ｌθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/983scCxuDgzPS8oMz2jRMM3M6@0WEfBJbMsMyVVI7g0V6NQU0fBJzUvvSQDyASyCzWtuQKKMvNKNJwTi0s0oCoLdRSCC0sTi1KD8vPhgiDtAfnlqUUgaSMUc0DA@v//6GhdYx1DHRMgNo2N/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
       θ    Input array
≧           Update each element
 ⁻          Subtract
   Σ        Sum of
    θ       Input array
  ∕         Divided by
     Ｌ      Length of
      θ     Input array
```

Calculate \$\mu\$ and vectorised subtract it from each \$x_i\$.

```
  θ         Updated array
 ∕          Vectorised divided by
   ₂        Square root of
     Σ      Sum of
       θ    Updated array
      Ｘ     Vectorised to power
        ²   Literal 2
    ∕       Divided by
         Ｌ  Length of
          θ Array
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print each element on its own line.
```

Calculate \$\sigma\$, vectorised divide each \$x_i\$ by it, and output the result.

Edit: Saved 6 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only for a) using `SquareRoot()` instead of `Power(0.5)` b) fixing vectorised `Divide()` (it was doing `IntDivide()` instead) c) making `Power()` vectorise.

Comment: crossed out 25 = no bytes? :P (Also, you haven't updated the TIO link yet)

Comment: @ASCII-only Oops, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <strike>33</strike> 23 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
{t%%(+/t*t:x-/x%#x)%#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukRVVUNbv0SrxKpCV79CVblCE4hr/6cp6BorGCqYALHpfwA)

First attempt at coding (I don't dare to name it "golfing") in K. I'm pretty sure it can be done much better (too many variable names here...)

Comment: nice! you can replace the initial `(x-m)` with `t` ([tio](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukRVVUNbv0SrxKpCN9eqWlu/QlW5orZCE0T@T1PQNVYwVDABYtP/AA))

Comment: the inner `{` `}` is unnecessary - its implicit parameter name is `x` and it has been passed an `x` as argument ([tio](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukRVVUNbv0SrxKpCV1u/QlW5QhOIa/@nKegaKxgqmACx6X8A))

Comment: another -1 byte by replacing `x-+/x` with `x-/x`. the left argument to `-/` serves as initial value for the reduction ([tio](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qukRVVUNbv0SrxKpCV79CVblCE4hr/6cp6BorGCqYALHpfwA))

Comment: @ngn Thank you! Now I see that the first 2 golfs are obvious; the last one is beyond my current level :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [numpy](http://www.numpy.org), 46 bytes

```python
lambda a:(a-mean(a))/std(a)
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRSiNRNzc1MU8jUVNTv7gkBUhzpRXl5yrkleYWVCpk5hbkF5Vo/S8oyswr0UjTiDbUMdIxjtXU5EIWQeHrGusY6pgAsSlQ@D8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 59 bytes

```hs
(%)i=sum.map(^i)
f l=[(0%l*y-1%l)/sqrt(2%l*0%l-1%l^2)|y<-l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYhLCoAgFAD3neItEjTS7LfLk0SBiyLpGZW2CLq7GbQYhplFu3VCDIESZpS7rLB6p6NhyQyoeioJZjcvCbLCHaenVez4vjNW7Lk7jkPwque1kHkZaX63Qg6J1WYDBftpNg8pzODDCw)

Doesn't use libraries.

The helper function `%` computes the sum of `i`th powers of a list, which lets us get three useful values.

- `0%l` is the length of `l` (call this `n`)
- `1%l` is the sum of `l` (call this `s`)
- `2%l` is the sum of squares of `l` (call this `m`)

We can express the z-score of an element `y` as

```hs
(n*y-s)/sqrt(n*v-s^2)
```

(This is the expression `(y-s/n)/sqrt(v/n-(s/n)^2)` simplified a bit by multiplying the top and bottom by `n`.)

We can insert the expressions `0%l`, `1%l`, `2%l` without parens because the `%` we define has higher precedence than the arithmetic operators.

`(%)i=sum.map(^i)` is the same length as `i%l=sum.map(^i)l`. Making it more point-free doesn't help. Defining it like `g i=...` loses bytes when we call it. Although `%` works for any list but we only call it with the problem input list, there's no byte loss in calling it with argument `l` every time because a two-argument call `i%l` is no longer than a one-argument one `g i`.

Comment: We do have \$\LaTeX\$ here:)

Comment: I really like the `%` idea! It looks just like the discrete version of the statistical *moments*.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
mc-dJ.OQ@.Om^-Jk2Q2
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mc-dJ.OQ%40.Om%5E-Jk2Q2&input=%5B-3%2C1%2C4%2C1%2C5%5D&debug=0).

```
mc-dJ.OQ@.Om^-Jk2Q2Q   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
                       Trailing Q inferred
    J.OQ               Take the average of Q, store the result in J
           m     Q     Map the elements of Q, as k, using:
             -Jk         Difference between J and k
            ^   2        Square it
         .O            Find the average of the result of the map
        @         2    Square root it
                       - this is the standard deviation of Q
m                  Q   Map elements of Q, as d, using:
  -dJ                    d - J
 c                       Float division by the standard deviation
                       Implicit print result of map
```

*Edit: after seeing [Kevin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177690/41020), changed to use the average builtin for the inner results. Previous answer: `mc-dJ.OQ@csm^-Jk2QlQ2`*

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 26 bytes

Trivial-ish, `std(,1)` for using population standard deviation

```
f=@(x)(x-mean(x))/std(x,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (83 series), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
Ans-mean(Ans
Ans/√(mean(Ans²
```

Takes input in `Ans`. For example, if you type the above into `prgmSTANDARD`, then `{1,2,3}:prgmSTANDARD` will return `{-1.224744871,0.0,1.224744871}`.

Previously, I tried using the `1-Var Stats` command, which stores the population standard deviation in `σx`, but it's less trouble to compute it manually.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅA-DnÅAt/
```

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177605/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKujrksekCzR//8/WtdYx1DHBIhNYwE) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeXiCvZLCo7ZJCkr2/w@3Ouq65AHJEv3/Ov@jow11jHSMY3UUQAwQpWusY6hjAsSmsbEA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅA          # Calculate the mean of the (implicit) input
            #  i.e. [-3,1,4,1,5] → 1.6
  -         # Subtract it from each value in the (implicit) input
            #  i.e. [-3,1,4,1,5] and 1.6 → [-4.6,-0.6,2.4,-0.6,3.4]
   D        # Duplicate that list
    n       # Take the square of each
            #  i.e. [-4.6,-0.6,2.4,-0.6,3.4] → [21.16,0.36,5.76,0.36,11.56]
     ÅA     # Pop and calculate the mean of that list
            #  i.e. [21.16,0.36,5.76,0.36,11.56] → 7.84
       t    # Take the square-root of that
            #  i.e. 7.84 → 2.8
        /   # And divide each value in the duplicated list with it (and output implicitly)
            #  i.e. [-4.6,-0.6,2.4,-0.6,3.4] and 2.8 → [-1.6428571428571428,
            #   -0.21428571428571433,0.8571428571428572,-0.21428571428571433,1.2142857142857144]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 229 bytes

```
	DEFINE('Z(A)')
Z	X =X + 1
	M =M + A<X>	:S(Z)
	N =X - 1.
	M =M / N
D	X =GT(X) X - 1	:F(S)
	A<X> =A<X> - M	:(D)
S	X =LT(X,N) X + 1	:F(Y)
	S =S + A<X> ^ 2 / N	:(S)
Y	S =S ^ 0.5
N	A<X> =A<X> / S
	X =GT(X) X - 1	:S(N)
	Z =A	:(RETURN)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDNasMwEITP2qfYWySaP5vmEqKCwHJZsJUiySD7kEPPpTn0/XF3HUMLpRchNDPf7Orr8/5@/3ieVeNbCl5vJu3MxoAKQ@87tBTehgzKxYiWDzfqRTBAitB2WdP28YCET1ipc6vbIZglcaGXFaDOmgywoMI19q6jyTdouSpGtjLoCPQ/0IeGXdchMwntD4H5AiYzT6qgLeIH1aPt@eYuhdWkJ9lFxB1W@1U9YIBGIq9ZF4OLJkVJ5uYcryrnDnvmc3cSL49WtkHc61gjuxPatJbhDWshc4Q540O64XF/gvCbesAEf7qTlj@b2MLx6PMQg5l577mGCupv)

Link is to a functional version of the code which constructs an array from STDIN given its length and then its elements, then runs the function `Z` on that, and finally prints out the values.

Defines a function `Z` which returns an array.

The `1.` on line 4 is necessary to do the floating point arithmetic properly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), 37 bytes

```julia
a->(a-mean(a))/std(a,corrected=false)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/59m@z9R104jUTc3NTFPI1FTU7@4JEUjUSc5v6goNbkkNcU2LTGnOFXzf0FRZl5JTp5Gmka0oY6RjnGspiYXqhiaiK6xjqGOCRCbAiX@AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 34 bytes

```
[ dup demean swap 0 std-ddof v/n ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYq9CsIwFEb3PsX3Ao0/1UUXN@niIk7SISS3GLRJyL1WRPrsMUWHj@9wOL02ElK@nNvTcYdBy02xaHEszjDulDw9fnqkuWTERCLvmJwX7KvqgxXWaDD9af66Kbgp22LKV9hnhKWBtAe/dMQSLLa2NvQYFx5dSZRS6GDCEAMTJLlD/gI)

Sadly, while Factor has the `z-score` word, it uses the sample standard deviation instead of the population standard deviation.